# Windows not showing in grub

Tags: windows, dual-boot, manjaro, boot-loader

**Short Story:**
I deleted the first partition and then created a new fat32 partition from it. Then installed manjaro. Now, I cant access Windows 10.

**Question**: How do I fix this, and get the windows 10 in my grub running?

**Long story:**
I had dual boot( windows and manjaro) on a HDD, i migrated to SSD using clonezilla. However, after plugging my SSD into the laptop i couldnt start windows, but i could start manjaro easily. So, I decided to install windows 10, after installation I couldnt access grub. I tried to fix this through manjaro live usb, but I couldnt install manjaro, so I deleted the first partition, then used installed manjaro. But that caused the windows to disappear from grub.

Comment: It sounds like you deleted Windows boot files. Was first partition the ESP - efi system partition. You need to run the full set of Windows repairs to reinstall the Windows boot files into the ESP. Use your Windows repair flash drive or repair console on installer.

Comment: is there no way to do this through linux?

Comment: No, almost all Windows fixes need Windows repair disk or installer. You can download full Windows ISO and create installer. But Windows made .win file larger than 4GB so it does not fit on a FAT32 formatted partition which is required for UEFI boot. Most older instructions assume its fits. I used the Windows tool to create an installer & it split .win into two parts. Do you not have good backups? Or a Windows repair flash drive? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156795/windows-hard-disk-read-only-now-windows-is-removed?noredirect=1#comment1925839_1156795

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by creating a windows installer disk by burning the iso to a drive using WoeUSB, i used NTFS.
After doing recovery through windows installer, I did sudo os-prober && sudo update-grub, and that solved the issue.